# df.to_html setting column width for each column using col_space

Tags: python, pandas

I was going through the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html
It says I can pass a list. My understanding is passing a list should set width for each column.

```
**col_space**: col_spacestr or int, list or dict of int or str, optional
The minimum width of each column in CSS length units. An int is assumed to be px units.
```

But it just passes the list to style

```
<tr style="text-align: right;">
  <th style="min-width: [200, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75];"></th>
  <th style="min-width: [200, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75];">filename</th>
  <th style="min-width: [200, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75];">type</th>
  <th style="min-width: [200, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75];">status</th>
  <th style="min-width: [200, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75];">message</th>
  <th style="min-width: [200, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75];">user</th>
  <th style="min-width: [200, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75];">date</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: What pandas version are you using? It works for me as expected for version 1.2.4, e.g. `df.to_html(col_space=range(len(df.columns)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading pandas from 0.25.0 to 1.xx.x helped to resolve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Read pandas df.to_html documentary. If your pandas version is below 0.25.0 it wont work. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html